# Would a regular expression operation on a javascript object alter its contents?

Tags: javascript

The following code does not behave as expected - the regex match runs and I receive the messages I expect if there is a match. But if `'msg'` contains the other text content I am looking for e.g 'searchstring2' (and I have verified via logging that it does), then running the regex match first seems to prevent the subsequent conditions from passing. Is it possible that the match operation is altering `'obj'`?

If I move the regex match to the end of the if/else queue then the other conditions work as expected.

```
spooky.on('remote.message', function(msg) {
    this.echo('======================');
    this.echo(msg);
    var obj = JSON.parse(msg);
    this.echo(obj.type);
    this.echo('remote message caught: ' + obj.match_state.toString());

    //this.echo(obj.stroke);
    regex = /(string_)(looking|whatever)([\d])/g;
    if(obj.stroke.match(regex)) {
         this.echo('physio message' + obj.stroke.match(regex)[0]);
         TWClient.messages.create({
         body:obj.stroke.match(regex)[0]+' match id: '+obj.matchid,
         ...
         }, function(err, message) {
          //error handling
         });
     }

    else if (obj.type.toString() == "searchstring2" && obj.match_state.toString() == "C") {
        this.echo(obj.type);
        TWClient.messages.create({
            body:obj.surname1 +' v '+obj.surname2+ ' started time: '+obj.utc_timestamp,
            ...
            if(err) {
                console.log(err, message);
            }
        });
    }

     else if (obj.type.toString() == "searchstring3" && obj.match_state.toString() =="F") {
        this.echo(obj.match_state);
        TWClient.messages.create({
            body:'match '+obj.matchid+' finished, time: '+obj.utc_timestamp,
         ...

        }, function(err, message) {
          //error handling
        });
    }




});
```

Comment: You forgot to `var` your regex variable

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression built with the `g` flag is a kind of iterator : Operations change its internal state.

You probably don't need this flag here.

You could also rewrite your code like this :

```
var regex = /(string_)(looking|whatever)([\d])/g,  // don't forget the var
    m  = obj.stroke.match(regex);
if (m) {
    this.echo('physio message' + m[0]);
    TWClient.messages.create({
    body:m[0]+' match id: '+obj.matchid,
```

which would avoid two useless `match` operations.

Comment: `if (m = obj.stroke.match(regex)) {` I'm guessing you mean `m ==` and the assignment should come before

Comment: @Deryck No, I really mean what I wrote. But in this case, it's true that there's no gain in the if(assignement) form.

Comment: @dystroy just so I am clear, you are saying that if I use /g for global match then the internal state of obj is changed?

Comment: @codecowboy Yes. That's why, for example, you never use the g flag with a regex if you intend to use the `test` function.